# BASH: Ctrl+C during input breaks current terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

My Bash version is: `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

I have a piece of code like this:

```
   while true; do
        echo -n "Set password: "
        read -s pass1
        printf "\n"
        echo -n "Repeat password: "
        read -s pass2
        printf "\n"
        if [ $pass1 != $pass2 ]; then
            echo "Not same."
        else
            break
        fi
    done
```

If I exit this script with `ctrl+c` while on the line reading `pass2` my terminal stops working properly.

```
user@host:~/bin$ user@host:~/bin$ user@host:~/bin$ user@host:~/bin$No command 'aaaa' found, did you mean...
```

Everything gets written to the same line and my typing is not echoed. I use Putty for these connections. When I connect to host again everyting is working again.

This problem only appears when certain conditions are true:
Only if it is run with `sudo`. Both normal user and root (became root with `sudo -s`) can exit the script without problem.

This problem exists only during second read statement. Exiting while reading `pass1` variable causes no trouble.

What could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: It's probably related to the `-s` option modifying your current terminal settings. Try adding `trap 'stty sane' INT` before the while loop, so that after you type Ctrl-C, the shell will try to fix your terminal before actually exiting.

Comment: This seems to be working. I can now exit the script even as sudo without problems.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38247336/982257) to a similar question I had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resetting your terminal should help. `read -s` is changing some settings to hide the input, and in some cases these settings aren't restored after the interrupt signal is received. Add this line to the beginning of the script to make sure your script resets the terminal to a good state:

```
trap 'stty sane' INT
```

As pointed out by User112638726, you should rather save the state of your terminal at the beginning of the script, and restore that (rather than assuming the original state is identical to what `sane` produces).

```
original_tty_state=$(stty -g)
trap "stty $original_tty_state" INT
```

Comment: You should really save your stty options at the start of the script and restore them rather than using sane.

Comment: You can just inline the variable: `trap "stty $(stty -g)" INT`.