# Running bash in subprocess breaks stdout of tty if interrupted while waiting on `read -s`?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, keyboardinterrupt

As @Bakuriu points out in the comments this is basically the same problem as in [BASH: Ctrl+C during input breaks current terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808863/bash-ctrlc-during-input-breaks-current-terminal)  However, I can only reproduce the problem when bash is run as a subprocess of another executable, and not directly from bash, where it seems to handle terminal cleanup fine.  I would be interested in an answer as to why bash seems to be broken in this regard.

I have a Python script meant to log the output of subprocess that is started by that script.  If the subprocess happens to be a bash script that at some point reads user input by calling the `read -s` built-in (the `-s`, which prevents echoing of entered characters, being key), and the user interrupts the script (i.e. by Ctrl-C), then bash fails to restore output to the tty, even though it continues to accept input.

I whittled this down to a simple example:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'read -s foo; echo $foo'])
p.wait()
```

Upon running `./test.py` it will wait for some input.  If you type some input and press Enter the script returns and echos your input as expected, and there is no issue.  However, if you immediately hit "Ctrl-C", Python displayed a traceback for the `KeyboardInterrupt`, and then returns to the bash prompt.  However, nothing you type is displayed to the terminal.  Typing `reset<enter>` successfully resets the terminal, however.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to exactly what's happening here.

**Update:** I managed to reproduce this without Python in the mix either.  I was trying to run bash in strace to see if I could glean anything that was going on.  With the following bash script:

```
$ cat read.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -s foo
echo $foo
```

Running `strace ./read.sh` and immediately hitting Ctrl-C produces:

```
...
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
brk(0x1a93000)                          = 0x1a93000
read(0, Process 25487 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Where PID 25487 was `read.sh`.  This leaves the terminal in the same broken state.  However, `strace -I1 ./read.sh` simply interrupts the `./read.sh` process and returns to a normal, non-broken terminal.

Comment: A little digging in the `bash` source shows how this works.  Silent mode just sets unsets the `ECHO` flag in the tty attributes, and then calls `add_unwind_protect` to restore the previous tty attributes.  I don't know how `add_unwind_protect` words though, or why it wouldn't be called before the process exits or is detached.

Comment: Isn't your question just a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808863/bash-ctrlc-during-input-breaks-current-terminal  ? The answer seems to be that is the responsibility of the script writer to restore the state of the terminal.  Note that you could write an intermediate script that simply stores the current terminal states and uses `trap` to restore it and calls the other script, if you cannot modify that.

Comment: @Bakuriu It looks like it might be the same thing.  The odd thing though is if I just run the bash script by itself it handles interrupts fine and restores the terminal state.  It's only when it's run as a subprocess of something other than bash where this fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is related to the fact that `bash -c` starts a **non-interactive** shell. This probably prevents it from restoring the terminal state.

To explicitly start an interactive shell you can just pass the `-i` option to bash.

```
$ cat test_read.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['bash', '-c', 'read -s foo; echo $foo'])
p.wait()
$ diff test_read.py test_read_i.py 
3c3
< p = Popen(['bash', '-c', 'read -s foo; echo $foo'])
---
> p = Popen(['bash', '-ic', 'read -s foo; echo $foo'])
```

When I run and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$ ./test_read.py
```

I obtain:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_read.py", line 4, in <module>
    p.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1648, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1598, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and the terminal isn't properly restored.

If I run the `test_read_i.py` file in the same way I just get:

```
$ ./test_read_i.py 

$ echo hi
hi
```

no error, and terminal works.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I just found this myself the hard way--by digging through the source code, and was right in the middle of answering this myself.  I'm going to complete my answer, but yours is definitely the right idea!

Comment: Turns out this is bug (in bash) is fixed in v4.4rc1

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment on my question, when `read -s` is run, bash saves the current tty attributes, and installs an `add_unwind_protect` handler to restore the previous tty attributes when the stack frame for `read` exits.

Normally, `bash` installs a handler for `SIGINT` at its startup which, among other things, invokes a full unwinding of the stack, including running all `unwind_protect` handlers, such as the one added by `read`.  However, this `SIGINT` handler is normally *only* installed if bash is running in *interactive* mode.  According to the source code, interactive mode is enabled only in the following conditions:

```
 /* First, let the outside world know about our interactive status.
     A shell is interactive if the `-i' flag was given, or if all of
     the following conditions are met:
    no -c command
    no arguments remaining or the -s flag given
    standard input is a terminal
    standard error is a terminal
     Refer to Posix.2, the description of the `sh' utility. */
```

I think this should also explain why I couldn't reproduce the problem simply by running bash from within bash.  But when I run it in `strace`, or a subprocess started from Python, I was either using `-c`, or the program's `stderr` is not a terminal, etc.

As @Baikuriu found in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247336/982257), posted just as I was in the process of writing this, `-i` will force `bash` to use "interactive mode", and it will clean up properly after itself.

For my part, I think this is a bug.  It *is* documented in the man page that if `stdin` is not a TTY, the `-s` option to `read` is ignored.  But in my example `stdin` *is* still a TTY, but bash is not otherwise technically in interactive mode, despite still invoking interactive behavior.  It should still clean up properly from a `SIGINT` in this case.

For what it's worth, here's a Python-specific (but easily generalizeable) workaround.  First I make sure that `SIGINT` (and `SIGTERM` for good measure) are passed to the subprocess.  Then I wrap the whole `subprocess.Popen` call in a little context manager for the terminal settings:

```
import contextlib
import os
import signal
import subprocess as sp
import sys
import termios

@contextlib.contextmanager
def restore_tty(fd=sys.stdin.fileno()):
    if os.isatty(fd):
        save_tty_attr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        yield
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, save_tty_attr)
    else:
        yield

@contextlib.contextmanager
def send_signals(proc, *sigs):
    def handle_signal(signum, frame):
        try:
            proc.send_signal(signum)
        except OSError:
            # process has already exited, most likely
            pass

    prev_handlers = []

    for sig in sigs:
        prev_handlers.append(signal.signal(sig, handle_signal))

    yield

    for sig, handler in zip(sigs, prev_handlers):
        signal.signal(sig, handler)


with restore_tty():
    p = sp.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'read -s test; echo $test'])
    with send_signals(p, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        p.wait()
```

I'd still be interested in an answer that explains why this is necessary at all though--why can't bash clean itself up better?

Comment: Well the bash maintainers at least agree it's a bug, since it turns out this is already fixed!  I noticed the fix is in bash 4.4rc1.  So that's edifying at least (and the fix was almost the same as what I was going to propose).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Done!